# Node Assertion Testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, tdd

Does anyone have good reference material for assertion testing in node? I wrote some simple programs and I want to write unit test with the inbuilt node modules but can't seem to find any proper reference material. A simple tutorial will also suffice. I am familiar with unit testing in python catching up shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for node.js should help:

https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html

Also this youtube video is pretty good:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2XCdkL4bWI